# How to call Ansible variables in a shell script?

Tags: shell, ansible

I am having some troubles to call some ansible in a shell script.

I declare my variables in the shell script calling my ansible variables like this:

```
var_shell= {{ var1_ansible }}{{ var2_ansible}}
```

When running the ansible playbook, I get this error: `{{: command not found`
I understand that the shell does not appreciate the `{{`

I tried as well to declare my variable with double quotes. But I logically receive a misinterpretation of the variable as it is understood as a string of characters

```
var_shell= "{{ var1_ansible }}{{ var2_ansible}}"
```

Do you have some solutions, inputs or examples of how to call ansible variables in my shell script?

**Shell script call in the playbook:**

```
  - name: Task
  command: "path/script.sh"
  become: yes
```

**SOLUTION: The space in the declaration was the issue, I should have used:
`var_shell="{{ var1_ansible }}{{ var2_ansible}}"`**

Thanks

Comment: Please show your playbook or at the very least the entire task you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `shell` variable declared wrongly.
Remove the space after `=` and try again:

```
var_shell="{{ var1_ansible }}{{ var2_ansible}}"
```